# When I build with eosio_build.sh script is -i: invalid option

Tags: build

I have cloned recursively repositories. Next I go cd ~/eosio/eos
and try

```
 ./scripts/eosio_build.sh
```

Is error: ./scripts/eosio_build.sh: line 126: set: -i: invalid option
Line 126:

```
( [[ ! $NAME == "Ubuntu" ]] && [[ ! $ARCH == "Darwin" ]] ) && set -i # Ubuntu doesn't support interactive mode since it uses dash + Some folks are having this issue on Darwin; colors aren't supported yet anyway
```

I have Linux Mint 20

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that Linux Mint isn't supported, so if I were you I would just try removing the `&& set -i` from the built script and try recompiling.
This might cause other issues, if it does let me know in a comment, if it works then also let us know here too.

You can also get pre-built binaries here if you just need the software: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v2.0.7